# What's a readable way to indicate both multi-measure rallentando and 8va?

Tags: notation, tempo, engraving, ottava

In a piece I'm working on I've got a 4-meas. *rallentando* to a new, slower tempo. The piano RH, in those same 4 measures, also has an *8va* section. Either of them I'd want to engrave spanning the 4 measures (*i.e. "rall. _ _ _ _ _"* or "*8va _ _ _ _ _*"), but both...?

I can't recall reading anything that's got two spanning markings like this simultaneous, and a quick skim through the library doesn't surface anything.

What's best practice for notating both of these instructions? Stacking them--which on top? Something else?

Comment: Is this solo piano music, with just two staves in the system; or are there more staves (like, for example, in a piano quartet, or a concerto)?  In solo piano music, tempo-related markings such as "rallentando" are sometimes placed between the staves, rather than above the upper staff.

Comment: Large ensemble, so the extracted piano part will be where this matters. (Well, medium ensemble, I guess. ~10 parts.)

Comment: But if it's a large ensemble, won't the piano part be the bottom two staves in each system?  So the speed marking will be at the very top of the system; whereas the 8va in the piano part will be above the second-to-bottom staff?  I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem in the piano player's (extracted) part they'll both need to be indicated.

Comment: So there ARE only two staves in the system.  Sorry, I thought you were talking about the score for the entire ensemble.  Then my earlier comment applies - the "rallentando" would likely be placed between the staves, whereas the 8va has to be above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend avoiding the spanning line for the *rallentando*. Instead, just mark *rall.* at the beginning of the passage and then *a tempo*, or a new tempo indication, after the fourth measure. That will be perfectly clear without the visual confusion of two spanning lines.

The *rall.* indication may be placed between the staves for additional clarity of reading.

Comment: If you *do* have a new tempo, you can also write "rallentando sin'al andante" for extra clarity.

Answer (score 4):

The 8va has to go above the notes so it doesn't get confused with 8vb, and it should be closer to the notes. Given that, you have to fit the rallentando in as best you can, maybe put it below the system, and maybe you can avoid the extension line.

Answer (score 3):

Tempo indications are written above the staff or staves but tempo **changes** are often placed below. Place the 8va above the RH staff and place the rall below the LH staff.

Comment: Schirmer disagrees, as do the overwhelming majority of scores I've seen: All tempo-related text goes above the staff, where the conductor will see it. Maybe this is a case for an exception, but it's not the style.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you - I've seen all "rit."/"rall."/"a tempo"/etc. indications go *between* the two piano staves. Maybe you're confusing the OP's "rall." marking with full-blown tempo indication changes such as "Presto".

Comment: @Dekkadeci So have I, but so far no one has recommended that. It's what I'd do: write the 8va with a line above, and then put the rall between the staves, with no line.